# replace data frame - special pattern

Tags: r, replace, gsub

Suppose I have the next data frame:

```
dd<-data.frame(a=c("xtr","la casa x-tr","x-tr"))

             a
          xtr
 la casa x-tr
         x-tr
```

How can I replace onlye the "x-tr" occurrencies with "xtr". So, final output would be

```
         a
          xtr
 la casa xtr
         xtr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
dd$a <- sub("(x)-(tr)$", "\\1\\2", dd$a)
dd$a
#[1] "xtr"         "la casa xtr" "xtr"
```

If there is only a single `-`, then

```
sub("-", "", dd$a)
```